# Webdriver/Firefox - how to specify another firefox installation

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

I want to create an instance of firefox, but not from the place it is looking for it - "/usr/bin/firefox", but from "/opt/firefox/firefox"
how can I do that here:

```
      FirefoxBinary firefox = new FirefoxBinary();
      firefox.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", "0");
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefox, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of FirefoxBinary takes a file argument!

```
File ffExe = new File("path/to/exe");
FirefoxBinary firefox = new FirefoxBinary(ffExe);
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the documentation of Selenium [1] you can specify your own executable file. Like this:

```
FirefoxBinary firefox = new FirefoxBinary(new File("/opt/firefox/firefox"));
firefox.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", "0");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefox, null);
```

[1] https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html